# How to display selected taxonomies by their parent?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy as 'services' and custom post type as 'portfolio'. What I would like to do is; I want to list all the selected services under their parent taxonomy in single page.

And here is my code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'services' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $parent = get_term_by('id', $term->parent, 'services');
    $parent_obj = get_term($parent->term_id, 'services');
    $parent_name = $parent_obj->name;

    echo $parent_name . ': ' . $term->name . '<br>';
}
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

- Design: Web, Graphic (selected child taxonomies)
- Development: App, Web App (selected child taxonomies)

This is the current result:

- Design: Web
- Design: Graphic
- Development: App
- Development: Web App